# Magento 2.3 upgrade breaks HTTP POST requests to custom module endpoint

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have a custom module with a defined route as:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="custom_module" frontName="custom-module">
            <module name="Custom_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

With previous versions of Magento both GET and POST requests would work fine to http://mywebsite.com/custom-module/controllername

After upgrading to Magento 2.3.0, GET requests still work as before, however POST requests now do not call the execute() method of the controller. Instead, they respond with a 200 OK and a response body that is the homepage html of the website.

Does this have to do with some Csrf security feature and form keys that was added in v2.3?

Comment: Anyone got this working for 2.3.5-p1? Really annoying Shipstation don't have anything.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Please check more generous solution that does not change core functionality, you can use around plugin on **Validate** function of **Magento\Framework\App\Request\CsrfValidator** class

> This implementation does not break the core functionality of Magento 2.1/2.2/2.3 versions.

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Request\CsrfValidator">
        <plugin name="csrf_validator_skip" type="Module\Vendor\Plugin\CsrfValidatorSkip" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**CsrfValidatorSkip.php**

```
<?php
namespace Module\Vendor\Plugin;
class CsrfValidatorSkip
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\CsrfValidator $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $action
     */
    public function aroundValidate(
        $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $request,
        $action
    ) {
        if ($request->getModuleName() == 'Your_Module_frontName_Here') {
            return; // Skip CSRF check
        }
        $proceed($request, $action); // Proceed Magento 2 core functionalities
    }
}
```

Please star my Gist page at https://gist.github.com/ananth-iyer/59ecfabcbca73d6c2e3eeb986ed2f3c4 to encourage.

Comment: $request->getModuleName() always return blank

Comment: @AnanthMage2 Can you tell me where to add this?

Comment: I am facing same issue. I added one or more custom modules. So, Can I need to add plugins in each and every module? If There are already exist di.xml files so what can I do?

Comment: How can I defeat the interlocks on my microwave?

Comment: @AndreNickatina, this is not redirecting to success page

Comment: I would hope not

Answer (score 29):

**UPDATE:** I changed the accepted answer to the one from @AnanthMage2 as it follows Magento's coding practices

---

Found the solution, your controller must implement CsrfAwareActionInterface and 2 of its methods:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException;

class MyController extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements CsrfAwareActionInterface
{
    public function createCsrfValidationException(RequestInterface $request): ?InvalidRequestException
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function validateForCsrf(RequestInterface $request): ?bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This solves the problem, but is also backwards incompatible, i.e. your module will now not work on Magento 2.2 and earlier. To make it backwards compatible, something like the following is needed:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException;

if (interface_exists("Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface"))
    include __DIR__ . "/MyController.m230.php";
else
    include __DIR__ . "/MyController.m220.php";
```

Where you would have the full and correct class declaration in each of the two files.

Comment: Working like a charm. this is what i am looking at.. thanks!!

Comment: Check this answer for backwards compatibility: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/261410/74078

Comment: The first part is great and compatible with 2.3. But the implementation of backward compatibility is out of the standards and Magento recommendations.

Comment: @RicardoMartins see the accepted answer for a standards based solution

Comment: where should I add this?

Comment: Used that solution to bypass error Request validation failed for action within ui_component massaction massdelete. Not sure why formkey wasn't going through but happy with workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Implement CsrfAwareActionInterface is a solution, but it makes the code not compatible with Magento < 2.3

Here is a trick (injecting the Key to the request on the Action) that is compatible with Magento 2.X

Put it in the constructor of the Action.

```
        // CsrfAwareAction Magento2.3 compatibility
        if (interface_exists("\Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface")) {
            $request = $this->getRequest();
            if ($request instanceof HttpRequest && $request->isPost() && empty($request->getParam('form_key'))) {
                $formKey = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey::class);
                $request->setParam('form_key', $formKey->getFormKey());
            }
        }
```

Comment: $this->getRequest() is null in the __construct ... I guess it's only available in the execute() method. So, it will never enter this if. Didn't work for me at least. Magento 2.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

No need to change csrf, here you can see the answer.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/263907/59683

Add headers in your request

```
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
```

And POST request on controller will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

One could provide a compatible solution to PHP 7.1< & Mage 2.3< if they were to outsource the validator to a different class, e.g.

```
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70100) {
    class Index extends Extendable\Main {}
} else {
    class Index extends Extendable\CsrCompatible {}
}
```

Where `Extendable\Main` has the logic for `execute() {}` and `CsrCompatible` can both extend `Extendable\Main` and `implements CsrfAwareActionInterface`. E.g:

```
class Main extends Action 
{
     execute() {...}
}
```

And

```
class CsrCompatible extends Main implements CsrfAwareActionInterface 
{
     //interface functions
}
```

The 5.6-7.0 will just never go into the `CsrCompatible` and therefore not throw an exception when it sees the fancy `?bool` code.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the implementation suggested by AnanthMage2 but was facing issue 
"$request->getModuleName() always return blank" as commented by sumeet bajaj.
Major issue which we were facing was order's were not getting completed within magento after order was shipped within shipstation.
So for temporary fix I have added below customization's within aroundValidate function:

```
class CsrfValidatorSkip {
    const CONTROLLER_MODULE = '/index.php/api/auctane';
    const CONTROLLER_NAME = '/api/auctane';

    /**
     * @param CsrfValidator $subject
     * @param Closure $proceed
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param ActionInterface $action
     */
    public function aroundValidate(
        $subject,
        Closure $proceed,
        $request,
        $action
    ) {
        // Skip CSRF check
        /* if ($request->getControllerModule() == self::CONTROLLER_MODULE
            && $request->getControllerName() == self::CONTROLLER_NAME) {
            return;
        }*/
        $requestUrlCforge = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
        if ($requestUrlCforge == self::CONTROLLER_MODULE
            || $requestUrlCforge == self::CONTROLLER_NAME) {
            return;
        }


        // Proceed Magento 2 core functionalities
        $proceed($request, $action);
    }
}
```