# LocalizedException: "An item needs to be selected. Select and try again."

Tags: magento2.3, email, newsletter, newsletter-subscriber

I am trying to customize [extension](https://github.com/magevision/magento2-mass-email-customers) by adding it to newsletter subscribers, and when I select/check subscribers and send email, I get error as the title suggests.

**Error:**

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): An item needs to be selected. Select and try again.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): An item needs to be selected. Select and try again.
<pre>#1 MageVision\MassEmailCustomers\Controller\Adminhtml\Email\MassSend->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
```

I have added necessary classes to the PHP i think, my code is below

https://github.com/nix0x00/newsletter_subscribers/blob/master/massSend.php

I assume its being thrown from line :119 `$this->send($item);`.

Can anyone please suggest me whats wrong here?

**My XML file is:**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.massaction">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="mass_email_customer" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email to Customers</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">massemailcustomers/email/massSend</item>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to send an email to the selected subscriber(s)?</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading your file, the send function does start by initiating inline translation and then at the end of the function terminate the inline translation.
I assume you’re doing this to enable your email to be translated in your store locale.

To do this, the more conventional way is to use store emulation process.

Below is the code to trigger a store emulation.

```
  public function __construct(
       ...
        \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $emulation,
        ..
    ) {
    $this->emulation->startEnvironmentEmulation(Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID, Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
     ...
    
    $this->emulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
```

Comment: I absolutely and totally did not get you xD

Comment: Thanks for your honesty, I updated my answer

Comment: ah I see, but even implementing this won't help me with the error I am getting. When I check (subscribed) customer and from action I click `Email to Customer` I does not show how many records I selected, but in Sales or Customer tab, it does show me record, and also as the error suggests, somehow its sending an empty subscriber list to `massSend.php` file.

Comment: Good shout, looks like your post data don’t go through. Will try to dig this tomorrow evening if still a problem at your end.

Comment: Your controller should implement httppostinterface.. that could explain why your post data don’t go through. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/253585/magento2-3-controller-wont-handle-post-method

Comment: in MassSend.php file, I have this code `$namespace = $this->getRequest()->getParam('namespace');` in execute method, and this is working fine for Customer & Sales, so does Newsletter need different implementation? although the link you sent doesn't mention that way for newsletter.

Comment: good response again!, really, look like we might need more of your code as I admit I don't know what is wrong at the moment

Comment: I have uploaded the extension (with my changes) > https://github.com/nix0x00/newsletter_subscribers/blob/master/magento2-mass-email-customers-master.zip < please check it. subscri*.xml is located in view/ad*/layout < and massSend.php file is in Controller. If you install, you will notice it works fine in Customer and Sales tab, but in Newsletter Subscribers, it gives error.