# Magento adding conditions on catalog price rules causes ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: redirect, catalog-price-rules

I am using Magento 2.3 installed via CPanel from hosting

I am trying to create a catalog price rule,
when I click on condition and selects Catalog it takes time to load then displays an error

I have tried this on multiple browsers , (my website not using https)

check the video I Captured for my problem

https://youtu.be/6B8qFuUgf_c

Comment: Same problem in 2.3.1, HTTPS ON. Backend set to english. Massive redirects to Dashboard, next screen indicates : "Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.". Same thing happens in "Cart Price Rule". Did you fix it ? Could be related : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/253414/magento-2-3-upgrade-breaks-http-post-requests-to-custom-module-endpoint

EDIT : seems to work on FF / Chrome since M2.3.2

Comment: Upgrading to v2.3.2 will solve your problem. (I had the same problem on 2.3.1).