# How to bypass CSRF validation for certain requests like payment gateway webhook?

Tags: payment-gateway, magento2.3, dependency-injection, magento2.3.0, csrf

I am trying to integrate CC avenue payment method with Magento 2.3 however once payment is processed, user is navigated back to website with error "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page."

Upon debugging, I found that CSRF validation fails when CC avenue posts response on return URL. While I also tried solution mentioned on the post : [Magento 2.3 upgrade breaks HTTP POST requests to custom module endpoint](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/253414/magento-2-3-upgrade-breaks-http-post-requests-to-custom-module-endpoint), still the error persists. Possible reason could be that interface mentioned in above post is not being used rather it gets into `Magento\Framework\App\Request\CsrfValidator` class which implements `Magento\Framework\App\Request\ValidatorInterface`.

Possible workaround is to override class - `Magento\Framework\App\Request\CsrfValidator` as follows:

```
public function validate(
        RequestInterface $request,
        ActionInterface $action
    ): void {
        try {
            $areaCode = $this->appState->getAreaCode();
        } catch (LocalizedException $exception) {
            $areaCode = null;
        }
        if ($request instanceof HttpRequest
            && in_array(
                $areaCode,
                [Area::AREA_FRONTEND, Area::AREA_ADMINHTML],
                true
            )
        ) {
            //Custom code
            if ($request->getRequestUri() == 'custom/uri')
            {
                $valid = true;
            }
            else {
                $valid = $this->validateRequest($request, $action);
            }
            if (!$valid) {
                    throw $this->createException($request, $action);
                }
            }
    }
```

Question is - how do I override this class? I tried writing dependency injection but did not work!

Comment: I have also faced the same issue. The solution in the link is working for me.

Comment: @Sree - For which version of Magento you faced this issue? I am facing it for Magento 2.3.0

Comment: When you say you tried writing dependency injection, do you mean that you tried setting a Preference in di.xml? If not, that'd be my first thing to try

Comment: @zack6849 - Yes I tried preference in di.xml with no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a `formKey` to your request.

Magento checks in the `validateRequest` function at `Magento\Framework\App\Request\CsrfValidator` if the request is intance of `CsrfAwareActionInterface`, not a post request, ajax or has a valide `formKey`:

```
private function validateRequest(
        HttpRequest $request,
        ActionInterface $action
    ): bool {
        $valid = null;
        if ($action instanceof CsrfAwareActionInterface) {
            $valid = $action->validateForCsrf($request);
        }
        if ($valid === null) {
            $valid = !$request->isPost()
                || $request->isAjax()
                || $this->formKeyValidator->validate($request);
        }

        return $valid;
    }
```

You can inject `Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey` and add to your request, something like this:

```
 $requestUrl .= '?form_key=' . $this->formKey->getFormKey();
```

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: @gemig_hol is this solution just for the cases where you specify a return url dynamically? Or can it also be used if the payment gateway webhook is always the same (pre-configured)

Comment: @snez the two payment method I worked I could add the form key to the request, I suppose if you can't change the return url this won't work.

Comment: M 2.3.3 Controller implementing CsrfAwareActionInterface was failing until added above workaround. Thanks for Sharing

Answer (score 0):

I went into the same problem on Magento 2.3.2 and found this buggy validation on 2.3.* versions.

I found the solution and a very simple composer package to make it easier for others.

This package simply disables the CSRF validation. Please use:

```
composer require gustavoulyssea/magento-csrf-validator-skip
```