# How to bypass CSRF validation for certain requests

Tags: magento2.3, validation, csrf

I am trying to bypass the CSRF validation for my Controller. I had seen a few workaround in the below links.

[Magento 2.3 upgrade breaks HTTP POST requests to custom module endpoint](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/253414/magento-2-3-upgrade-breaks-http-post-requests-to-custom-module-endpoint)

But I need my Module compatible with both Magento 2.2 and 2.3. So, I had overridden a core file `Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http` like below

```
public function isAjax()
{
   if ($this->getRequestUri() == 'custom/url') {
        return true;
   }
    if ($this->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return true;
    }
    if ($this->getParam('ajax') || $this->getParam('isAjax')) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

To bypass the `validateRequest()` function in `Magento\Framework\App\Request\CsrfValidator`

```
private function validateRequest(
    HttpRequest $request,
    ActionInterface $action
): bool {
    $valid = null;
    if ($action instanceof CsrfAwareActionInterface) {
        $valid = $action->validateForCsrf($request);
    }
    if ($valid === null) {
        $valid = !$request->isPost()
            || $request->isAjax()
            || $this->formKeyValidator->validate($request);
    }

    return $valid;
}
```

It was working fine. I want to know does it affect the technical review in the Magento Marketplace in any way (or) is there any other better way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first step is getting it passing the code quality checks.  Are you using this?

https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard

Comment: Hi, @DominicXigen I didn't start to check the coding standard for my Module yet.

Comment: Sidenote, your plugin could be an after instead of around since you are just modifying the result. Would give a slight performance increase and avoid unnecessarily increasing the call stack

Comment: Thanks, @Sam I had updated my code.

Comment: The amount of work required to bypass the validation seems more than making sure you can pass (which is the better option in my opinion). As a first step make sure that your form has a form_key and is submitted alongside the POST request.

Comment: @KristofatFooman The controller action can be triggered at any time dynamically(1-30 days) from another server. How can I have the valid form key at the time of execution?

Answer (score 2):

**Answer #1**: I'd recommend creating a webapi endpoint instead of an ajax controller. If you look at Magento core, the checkout is has many ajax calls and they all point to webapi endpoints which are defined in vendor/magento/module-checkout/etc/webapi.xml. You can define resources to make access to the controller as public or as restricted as you want.

**Answer #2**: Make sure that your form key is being properly submitted and check for any other requirements.

**Answer #3**: Maybe the easiest but absolutely one I don't recommend. However, since it works, I'll post it here. See code below.

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Bar\Controller\Baz;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;

/**
 * Class Index
 *
 * @package Foo\Bar\Controller\Baz
 */
class Index extends Action implements \Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @return ResponseInterface|ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var ResultInterface $result */
        $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $result->setData(['whatever data']);

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     *
     * @return bool|null
     */
    public function validateForCsrf(RequestInterface $request): ?bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     *
     * @return InvalidRequestException|null
     */
    public function createCsrfValidationException(RequestInterface $request): ?InvalidRequestException
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please let us know why Answer #3 is not recommend?

Comment: @Vish it is disabling necessary security protocols. It's a quick fix that could make your code more vulnerable. Remember, just because you can doesnt mean you should. Webapi is really the best way to go.

Comment: If anyone wants to bypass CSRF then I think this is a correct and fastest way. Obviously it will skip all validtaoin and security protocal but this question is itself for bypassing it :) Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It is not a best practice, its just easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard mixed things about the technical review. If your code passes the code quality check https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard you are with a good chance of passing.

But also as a rough guide

https://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/sellers/technical-review-guidelines.html

> Quality Assurance (M2 only): Pass Manual QA
>
> This check verifies that the extension installs without error, is configurable (as applicable), and operates as expected.
>
> To pass Manual QA, the extension must meet the following requirements:
>
> Installs with Composer,
>
> Compiles without errors using the following command: deploy:mode:set production
>
> Works with each version of Magento that is shown as supported in the extension product profile.
>
> Works with each version of PHP that is supported by the 
>   Magento version that is shown as supported in the extension product profile.
>
> Has all functionality that is described in the extension documentation.
>
> Does not crash with unhandled errors.
>
> Does not hang when invalid data is submitted.