# Magento2: why all my post request to my controller been forward

Tags: magento2, controllers, payment

I'm developing a module for the payment method.

So I need to revise post requests with pay results but all Post requests send to my controller been forward to the home page.

If request type is Get, my controller can revise request.

I try to sent Post request to magento2 another URL, still been forward to the home page.
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error like "Request validation failed" or "CSRF token mismatch" in the error log?

Comment: No, never get error .just  http cod 302 ,and return home page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

magento2.3 problem.

[Magento 2.3 upgrade breaks HTTP POST requests to custom module endpoint](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/253414/magento-2-3-upgrade-breaks-http-post-requests-to-custom-module-endpoint/255082#255082)

Thanks this answer help me to revice POST request in controller.